# How to handle non-existent subdirectories?

Tags: php, apache2, configuration

I have a dynamic website with friendly URLs. Example:

- Instead of `/user.php?id=123`, I have `/user/123`
- Instead of `/index.php?category=fishes`, I have `/fishes`

But, how do I handle non-existent subdirectories such as `/about/123`? Currently it gives a 200 success instead of a 404 not found error. Is there a way to deal with non-existent subdirectories in Apache config and at the same time allow for friendly URLs? Or do I have to handle this individually for each PHP script?

Comment: What PHP application are you using? How are you handling friendly URLs? These should 404 under normal conditions.

Comment: @closetnoc, I am using proxypass method with php-fpm as the fcgi handler. For handling friendly URLs, the php script itself does an extraction of the parameters using server path info.

Comment: But presumably /user and /fishes are not actually sub directories on the file system either - in which how would Apache know the difference? If /about/123 returns a 200 status, what response are you actually returning?

Comment: @w3d, `/about` is a valid about page so `/about/123` is returning the about page. I think because I am using proxypass, Apache would not know if the page is non-existent.

Comment: apache proxy pass will also proxy pass the headers.  So you want to use PHP logic to return the 404 header and you should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensured all the wanted folder names were present in the regex list then all others could be redirected to a 404 page using this .htaccess script:

```
# If friendly URL dynamic folder not present in URL then respond HTTP 404
RewriteRule ^(user|fishes) - [R=404]
```